# How to solve equations of type $a*x^c+b*x^d-S==0$?

Tags: nonlinear-system

How to solve the following equation

$$ a*x^c+b*x^d-S==0 $$
for $x$.

Wolfram alpha and sympy are not able to solve this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe a symbolic solution doesn't exist.

Comment: Can I test somehow if there is a closed form solution at all? And if there isn't can I predict how many numerical solutions I can expect for given a,b,c,d,S?

Comment: For some examples sure,$$c=2,d=3$$